# MySQL de Xampp no levanta

Tags: mysql, windows, xampp

Ayer que terminé mi jornada laboral cerré todo con ALT + F4, estuve trabajando con laravel, xampp y mysql. Algo raro que sucedió es que al apagar mi laptop tardo bastante en apagarse y como que se congeló.

Hoy al iniciar a trabajar, abrí el xampp, levanté apache y funcionó, levanté MySQL y aparecieron algunos errores.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al cambiar el puerto de MySQL si se levanta pero al abrir el localhost/phpmyadmin no me muestran mis bases de datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisé el archivo log de MySQL y estos son los registros del error.

```
2023-08-17 14:45:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-08-17 14:45:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-08-17 14:45:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2023-08-17 14:45:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-08-17 14:45:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2023-08-17 14:45:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2023-08-17 14:45:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-08-17 14:45:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-08-17 14:45:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-08-17 14:45:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-08-17 14:45:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-08-17 14:45:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence number 1028716819; transaction id 2656042
2023-08-17 14:45:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2023-08-17 14:45:48 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-08-17 14:45:48 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Alguien tiene alguna idea de como solucionarlo?
Saludos.

Comment: Verifica en qué puerto está corriendo `mysql` y si el firewall no está bloqueando ese puerto.

Comment: No esta corriendo ninguna aplicación :(

Comment: No me refiero a eso, me refiero a mysql en sí mismo. ¿No lo tienes instalado? ¿No está iniciado? MySQL debe conectarse a un puerto, y puede que el firewall esté bloqueando ese puerto.